Missing font: I can't find file `pcrr8t'
Building a Doxygen auto-generaten latex file, I am getting:
kpathsea: Running mktextfm pcrr8t
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation  for pcrr8t.
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update ?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input pcrr8t
This is METAFONT, Version 2.71828182 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded base=mf)

kpathsea: Running mktexmf pcrr8t
! I can't find file `pcrr8t'.
<*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input pcrr8t
                                                  
Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input pcrr8t
                                                  
Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: pcrr8t.log: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input pcrr8t' failed to make pcrr8t.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font T1/pcr/m/n/10=pcrr8t at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found

Can someone please tell me how to fix this? I tried
$ tlmgr install pcrr8t

But it cannot find that font.  The missfont.log file reads:
mktextfm pcrr8t
mktextfm pcrr8t
mktextfm pcrr8t
mktextfm pcrro8t
mktextfm nullfont


what does tlmgr info pcrr8t.tfm report?

Try installing the courier package via tlmgr install courier.

@DavidCarlisle Unfortunately there seems to be a bug in tlmgr, because for files it shows only HASH(…) instead of package names for files matching pccr8t.tfm.

@cabohah yes in tl2024 (it's fixed at source) but the OP is using tl2022 and I think it should work in that case.

@DavidCarlisle Thanks for the information. So I don't need to write a bug report.

@cabohah https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2024-May/050583.html

@DavidCarlisle Hm, this is only about the uninitialized value but not about the output of the hash address instead of the hash values. I'll try to install the tlcritical version next week to see, if this is also fixed.

If you look at the start of that thread the hash message is shown, although I admit I haven't tested the fix

@muzimuzhiZ: Thank you; installing courier did the trick.
